# TSQL equivalent Postgres Function

Tags: postgresql

How can we code a Postgres Function equivalent code for the below T SQL code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Testproc
AS
BEGIN
    Select * from MyTable
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most simple example of a set returning function.

```
create function testproc()
  returns setof mytable
as
$$
  select * from mytable;
$$
language sql;
```

For more examples, see the manual:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-EXAMPLES
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html

Comment: How can I return a TABLE result without specifying the Table column structure? The manual does not specify that! In the above scenario, I would like to create a generic function which can return any table.

Comment: That is a totally different question, please ask a new one.

Comment: : Please do not comment on this Question. You are not being of any help to me as you have not understood my difficulty. Thanks for your time anyways.

Comment: @RohitSurve This does exactly what you asked for in your question. If you want something different you should have asked a different question.